# Can I connect my PS3 to a monitor and output sound elsewhere?

Tags: ps3, monitor, audio-hardware

I want to connect my PS3 to my monitor instead of my TV. When I searched this, I read somewhere that you can only connect the PS3 to a monitor with speakers and HDMI cable.

Is that true? Does the PS3 has no direct sound output for connecting to other speakers or headphones? Or, if I use a monitor with speakers but no HDMI input (via a converter), would I lose sound that way or not?

Comment: If you want to know which thing is "good", especially without defining what that means, that's opinion based. This might get closed due to that phrasing. However, it looks to me like you're actually asking "how do I connect my PS3 to a computer monitor and still get sound". Is that what you're asking?

Comment: do you really search for something to downvote? i just asked searching for a way to connect ps3 to monitor without built in speaker @DCShannon

Comment: You could try rewording your question title to explicitly ask that instead of asking for a monitor recommendation, as @DCShannon pointed out. Currently, your question body and title don't really agree and unfortunately what the title itself asks is opinion based/off topic.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but I did see it in the close queue and offer advice about how to keep that from happening.

Comment: I did downvote thid question, and you are not just asking if there is a way to hook up sound, at all. The fact that you intend to suggests more problems with this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. "What monitor is good for ps3", in itself, has some issues with being opinion-based. That said, asking how to connect a PS3 for audio has a base answer; The same way you should connect a Blu Ray player for audio. The same way you should connect a HD Set Top Box for audio. As it is, that sort of question is off topic, as it is not gaming related. The general rule is that if you can replicate the problem without the console, its not within our scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want a monitor with speakers that is HDCP compliant. This requires the least amount of extra parts since you can just plug the PS3 straight into the monitor and get both the video and audio output.

If your monitor isn't HDCP compliant, video wont output to the monitor but you can use [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004F9LVXC) to get around it.

If you're using DVI, you're going to have to get an HDMI to DVI converter and a converter for the AV audio outputs to speakers. (You can in fact use the output from both the AV and HDMI out. This is recommended by Rocksmith for their games actually.)

I'm currently using the splitter I linked above to plug into my monitor (not HDCP compliant). The monitor had an 1/8" audio output that I plugged some cheap speakers into.

Comment: Do all splitters provide HDCP compliance, or does that have to be checked? Telling the user they just need (link) is helpful.. right up until the link dies

Comment: Not all splitters are compliant. It would seem that a lot just have pass through. I had to pour through reviews to make sure. Even listings that stated they were compliant seemed to have a lot of complaints stating otherwise.